# Drawing lots of CAShapeLayers with better performance

Tags: ios, swift, performance, drawing, core-graphics

I am drawing my own Map in an UIView and getting very poor performance: 3 Frames per second.

Situation:
In SWIFT I have an array of CAShapeLayers. Say every Country has it's own CAShapeLayer.
I created one CALayer and simply added all CAShapeLayers to it. The CALayer is then added to my UIView. When I translate the view (moving the map around) I get 3 frames per second.

Is my approach to drawing the shapes correct, or is there another way to get better performance? Is there anything else that would ensure better performance ? Or is it probably SWIFT, that is causing performance issues?

Comment: There could be many reasons for this. You're probably forcing something to draw much more often than it should. You might have a poor algorithm in your system that's eating all your CPU time, unrelated to drawing. You might be trying to access UIKit from a background thread. It could be dozens of things.  Start by investigating with Instruments and finding where your issues are. Try changing things (reducing layers for instance) to see what the system is sensitive to. Create a simpler project that demonstrates it. That's how to debug performance.